# 500 Internal Server Error while accessing the limesurvey survey token management page

Tags: php, limesurvey

Getting an 500 Internal server error on accessing the survey token management page and the apache error log says that,

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function FetchRow() on a non-object
>   in /var/www/html/limesurvey/admin/tokens.php on line 707, referer:
>   http://****/limesurvey/admin/admin.php?sid=55876.

Here is the tokens.php line no : 707

```
$tksq = "SELECT count(*) FROM ".db_table_name("tokens_$surveyid")." WHERE (sent!='N' and sent<>'')";
$tksr = db_execute_num($tksq);
while ($tkr = $tksr->FetchRow())
{
    $tokenoutput .= "<th>".$clang->gT("Total invitations sent")."</th><td> $tkr[0] / $tkcount</td></tr><tr>\n";
}
```

Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Check you table name. Is it correct "tokens_$surveyid"?  @sudhakaranR87

Comment: @AnkiiG : yes, The table is available on the DB. table name : tokens_55876

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
$surveyid = 55876;
$tablename = db_table_name("tokens_$surveyid");
$tksq = "SELECT count(*) FROM ".$tablename." WHERE (sent!='N' and sent<>'')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to last 2.06 or 2.50 :

- https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/2.06lts/application/controllers/admin/tokens.php#L707
- https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/controllers/admin/tokens.php#L707

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue resolved and its due to that survey table was crashed and then repaired the whole database.its worked.